# Entity Framework doesn't create Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i'm creating a database with entity framework, in an mvc asp.net application, using code first.

I'm new to the argument so be patient... I've created the database for the first time and all seems to be right; but couse of i didn't create a DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges method to change the tables i decided to manually delete the database.

The problem is that the database is not recreating!

I've implemented the initializer and it is in a different class from the context...

```
public class WidgetDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<WidgetDbContext>
    {
}
```

Setted it up in Global.asax.cs and forced to init that

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Database.SetInitializer<Portale.Models.WidgetDbContext>(new Portale.Models.WidgetDbInitializer());
        var _initer = new WidgetDbInitializer();

        using (var db = new WidgetDbContext())
        {
            _initer.Seedit(db);
            db.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
    }
```

I've just the default connection string couse now i don't care about it...

Please help me i've read tons of articles over the web and i can't get a solution...

The error i get:

```
System.ArgumentNullException non è stata gestita dal codice utente
  Message=Il valore non può essere null.
Nome parametro: key
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=key
  StackTrace:
       in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
       in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
       in System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.SortedEntityTypeIndex.Add(EdmEntitySet entitySet, EdmEntityType entityType)
       in System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingService.Analyze()
       in System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingService.Configure()
       in System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
       in System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
       in System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
       in System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
       in System.Linq.Queryable.Join[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](IQueryable`1 outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Expression`1 outerKeySelector, Expression`1 innerKeySelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)
       in Portale.Controllers.WidgetContainerController.Index() in C:\Users\doompro\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Portale\Portale\Controllers\WidgetContainerController.cs:riga 56
       in lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       in System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       in System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       in System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: The database will only be created once you do something in your application to access it. If you write some code that tries to access it, and then you run it, what happens? If the database doesn't get created, you must get an error, right?

Comment: Yes, every time i try to do something; FOR EXAMPLE CREATEIFNOTEXIST -.- i got an exception error, the parameter KEY can't be null. This for every operation i try to do to database. The database.mdf still not be created in data folder of sqlexpress, neither in the app_data of my application, it just not exist

Comment: Add the code you are using to access the database and the error you get as a result.

Comment: public void Init(WidgetDbContext context)
        {
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

Comment: error: ArgumentNullException , the parameter "key" can't be null. And i get this error every time i try access to database, adding element, selecting element; with elements not null

Comment: actually post the full error message and stack trace, and post it as an edit to the question so that it is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

override Seed function in your WidgetDbInitializer  class and try to add some data to your database .

```
protected override void Seed(WidgetDbContext context)
{

context.yourodel.add(new class() )
}
```

first check your overriden seed invoke correctly , then if your  database dose not generated you will   get an exception  .

Comment: I've already tried it, every time i try to access to database i get the same error: ArgumentNullException , the parameter "key" can't be null. And the database is still not created; either when there is no parameter key for the method, or when i pass an element with key attribute not null to insert into the database

Comment: >Portale.DLL!Portale.Models.WidgetDbInitializer.Init(Portale.Models.WidgetDbContext context) Line 15 
>Portale.DLL!Portale.MvcApplication.Application_Start() Line 47 + 0xd byte

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem:

```
public class Widget
{
    //This properties rapresent the primary key for entity framework
    [Key]
    public int WidgetID { get; set; }
    //Foreing key to the column where this widget is stored
    public virtual int ColumnID { get; set; }
    //The title of the widget
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //Controller of the Widget, this property may be used on the RenderAction call
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    //ActionMethod of the Widget, this property may be used on the RenderAction call
    public string ActionMethod { get; set; }
    //The Type of the Model, used on deserialization
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }
    //The context of the widget
    public string SerializedModel { get; set; }
}
```

The database just didn't accept the type "Type", all working fine as soon as I deleted that field... I just didn't look at it because it was working with the "Object" type, didn't expect it doesnt with Type..